# Remove trailing slash from ALL URL in multilingual site

Tags: .htaccess, multilingual, trailing-slash

I want to remove trailing slashes from www.my-site-domain/de/bilder-gallerie/. and other 5/6 URLs. My site is multilingual site. I used WPML plugin for my WP site.

I used the following rules in several times in htaccess to remove trailing slashes from all URLs.

1.
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=302,NE,L]`
after RewriteEngine On

2.
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R]`
after RewriteEngine On

3.
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]`
after RewriteEngine On.

These all are rules working fine. But, it is not working for home page for french and deutsch language.

It's through ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Please help.